# Log4Net with Asp.NET MVC, entity framework and dependency injection using NInject

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dependency-injection, ninject, log4net

Just started with Log4Net, read the [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140911/log4net-Tutorial) and got up with a simple console application. But I am wondering how to get started with MVC and entity framework code first with dependency Injection using NInject. Can some one please give some pointers?

Comment: Came accross this book Mastering Ninject for Dependency Injection. Guess this is what I need.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to use Ninject, and you will find a lot of tutorials out there.. most of them are old and will tell you to use ancient ways to do it (avoid anything that tells you to create a ControllerFactory or to derive your own NinjectApplication based Application.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out the MVC Ninject extension:
https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc

or from Nuget: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.MVC5/

> Once you do this, your controllers will be activated via Ninject,
>   meaning you can expose dependencies on their constructors (or
>   properties, or methods) to request injections.

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks. Looking into it.